# speed of an animation in canvas depends on the js engine speed, is there a way to make an animation appear the same in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

this is a link to a canvas animation
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-linear-motion-animation/

now just like with a regular js animation, the speed of it depends on how fast the browser is with js.
so my question is, does canvas have a way of bringing them all to the same level? or is there already a solution for this?

Comment: I can't notice a difference between Chrome & FF4. What browsers are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, in Javascript, `setInterval()` does not give you reliable timing, especially if the browser is too slow to update a frame in the time alotted.

So for each frame you have to calculate time elapsed since the previous frame, and use that to update your position.

Here is a live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/txWqJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the canvas to render at the same speed use

`setTimeout(doMoreRendering, 1000 / fps)`

Comment: its still javascript, i gave that link only as an example. but im talking about how mozila or ie have a far slower js engine than google and opera. thats what it has to do with.

Comment: @Petre that's wrong. IE9 / FF4 / Chrome / Safari5 are all roughly equally fast.